# Acceder a un documento .txt online con cmd/bat

Tags: web, archivo, cmd, batch, conexión

aunque no es exactamente lo que quiero hacer me gustaría saber si hay alguna forma de trabajar con un documento de texto que esté subido en la nube (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Xaival/AdBlockList/main/Adblock_list.txt) y acceder a él desde el cmd o .bat para poder usarlo como un archivo que esté ubicado en el equipo.

```
type https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Xaival/AdBlockList/main/Adblock_list.txt > %USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Document.txt
```

Para ejemplo supongamos que quiero crear un archivo en el escritorio a raíz de este.
¿De qué manera tendría que ponerse si es que se puede para poder acceder a él?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usa:

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Xaival/AdBlockList/main/Adblock_list.txt --output %USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Document.txt
```

y Listo :)

Comment: Muchas gracias, ha funcionado a la perfección ahora me queda probar si se puede hacer con paginas que no sean archivos .txt

¿Por cierto sabes algún sito con documentación para aprender de funciones avanzadas de cmd como esta?